# Asynctask used by multiple Java Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am currently working on a project, where I fetch data from a JSON dump, on Android. So far, have I set up a customised Asynctask in every fragment, where I need to fetch data from the JSON dump. What I am curious about is whether I can have one public Java class, which the fragments can just "use" whenever they need to fetch data.

This is an example of how i have attempted to do this. First the fragment who calls the Asynctask from a public java class:

```
public class DataTabelFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView sensor1;
private Button jsonButton;

jsonAsynctask jsonasynctask = new jsonAsynctask();


public DataTabelFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_data_tabel, container, false );

    sensor1 = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.sensor1Box );
    //jsonButton = (Button) view.findViewById( R.id.buttonjson );

    new jsonAsynctask().execute();

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonasynctask.allId.size(); i++) {
        sensor1.append( jsonasynctask.allId.get( i ) + " | " + jsonasynctask.allDevice.get( i ) + " | " + jsonasynctask.allTemp.get( i ) + " | " + jsonasynctask.allHum.get( i ) + " | " + jsonasynctask.allBat.get( i ) + " | " + jsonasynctask.allMode.get( i ) + " | " + jsonasynctask.allLux.get( i ) + " | " + jsonasynctask.allDate_time.get( i ) + "\n\n" );

    }

    //new jsonConnection().execute();

    /*

    jsonButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new jsonConnection().execute();
        }
    } );*/



    return view;

}


}
```

Here's the java class with the Asynctask:

```
public class jsonAsynctask extends MainActivity {

private TextView sensor1;
private Button jsonButton;

JSONObject deviceArray;
JSONObject tempArray;
JSONObject humArray;
JSONObject batArray;
JSONObject modeArray;
JSONObject date_timeArray;
JSONObject luxArray;

JSONArray json2;

List<String> allId = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allDevice = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allTemp = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allHum = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allBat = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allMode = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allDate_time = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allLux = new ArrayList<String>();

String basicAuth;
String line;
String json_string;
String json;
String cxwebURL;
String credentials;
String password;
String username;

Gson gson;
ProgressDialog pd;
String data = "";
HttpURLConnection connection;
BufferedReader bufferedReader;

String id = "";
JSONObject idArray;

URL url;

private static String encodeBase64URLSafeString(byte[] binaryData) {

    return android.util.Base64.encodeToString( binaryData, android.util.Base64.URL_SAFE );

}

public class jsonConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        username = "xxx";

        password = "xxx";

        credentials = username + ":" + password;

        cxwebURL = "https://" + credentials + "@xxx.com/fetch.php?device=xxx";

        try {

            url = new URL( cxwebURL );

            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            basicAuth = "Basic " + new String( encodeBase64URLSafeString( credentials.getBytes() ) );

            connection.setRequestProperty( "Authorization", basicAuth );
            connection.setRequestMethod( "GET" );
            connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
            connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Language", "en-US" );
            connection.setUseCaches( false );
            connection.setDoInput( true );
            connection.setDoOutput( true );
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( stream ) );

            line = "";

            while (line != null) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data + line;
            }

            json2 = new JSONArray( data );

            for (int i = 0; i < json2.length(); i++) {
                idArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                deviceArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                tempArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                humArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                batArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                modeArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                date_timeArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                luxArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                id = idArray.getString( "id" );

                String temp = tempArray.getString( "temp" );
                String device = deviceArray.getString( "device" );

                String hum = humArray.getString( "hum" );

                String bat = batArray.getString( "bat" );

                String mode = modeArray.getString( "mode" );

                String date_time = date_timeArray.getString( "time" );

                String lux = luxArray.getString( "light" );

                allId.add( id );
                allDevice.add( device );
                allTemp.add( temp );
                allHum.add( hum );
                allBat.add( bat );
                allMode.add( mode );
                allDate_time.add( date_time );
                allLux.add( lux );


            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd = new ProgressDialog( new MainActivity() );
        pd.setMessage( "Være sød at vente" );
        //pd.setCancelable( false );
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute( result );
        if (pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }

        System.out.println( data );

        gson = new Gson();

        json = gson.toJson( data );

        System.out.println( "String json: " + json );

        json_string = data;

        System.out.println( "json_string: " + json_string );

//            System.out.println( "DET HER ER ID!!: " + allId.get( 1 ) );

        //textView2.setMovementMethod( new ScrollingMovementMethod() );


        System.out.println("Size of Array: " + allId.size());



    }
        }


}
```

Am I able to do program it like this, or should I continue to have an Asynctask in each fragment? By the way, "new jsonAsynctask().execute();" in the fragment does not work and i receive this error:

> error: cannot find symbol class execute

*** Update ***

Here's the update in the Java Class, where the Asynctask is.

```
public class jsonAsynctask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private TextView sensor1;
private Button jsonButton;

JSONObject deviceArray;
JSONObject tempArray;
JSONObject humArray;
JSONObject batArray;
JSONObject modeArray;
JSONObject date_timeArray;
JSONObject luxArray;

JSONArray json2;

List<String> allId = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allDevice = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allTemp = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allHum = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allBat = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allMode = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allDate_time = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> allLux = new ArrayList<String>();

String basicAuth;
String line;
String json_string;
String json;
String cxwebURL;
String credentials;
String password;
String username;

Gson gson;
ProgressDialog pd;
String data = "";
HttpURLConnection connection;
BufferedReader bufferedReader;

String id = "";
JSONObject idArray;

URL url;

private static String encodeBase64URLSafeString(byte[] binaryData) {

    return android.util.Base64.encodeToString( binaryData, android.util.Base64.URL_SAFE );

}

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        username = "xxx";

        password = "xxx";

        credentials = username + ":" + password;

        cxwebURL = "https://" + credentials + "@xxx.com/fetch.php?device=xxx";


        try {

            url = new URL( cxwebURL );

            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            basicAuth = "Basic " + new String( encodeBase64URLSafeString( credentials.getBytes() ) );

            connection.setRequestProperty( "Authorization", basicAuth );
            connection.setRequestMethod( "GET" );
            connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
            connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Language", "en-US" );
            connection.setUseCaches( false );
            connection.setDoInput( true );
            connection.setDoOutput( true );
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( stream ) );

            line = "";

            while (line != null) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data + line;
            }

            json2 = new JSONArray( data );


            for (int i = 0; i < json2.length(); i++) {
                idArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                deviceArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                tempArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                humArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                batArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                modeArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                date_timeArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                luxArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );
                id = idArray.getString( "id" );

                String temp = tempArray.getString( "temp" );

                String device = deviceArray.getString( "device" );


                String hum = humArray.getString( "hum" );

                String bat = batArray.getString( "bat" );

                String mode = modeArray.getString( "mode" );

                String date_time = date_timeArray.getString( "time" );

                String lux = luxArray.getString( "light" );

                allId.add( id );
                allDevice.add( device );
                allTemp.add( temp );
                allHum.add( hum );
                allBat.add( bat );
                allMode.add( mode );
                allDate_time.add( date_time );
                allLux.add( lux );


            }


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd = new ProgressDialog( new MainActivity() );
        pd.setMessage( "Være sød at vente" );
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute( result );
        if (pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }

        gson = new Gson();

        json = gson.toJson( data );

        json_string = data;


      }
        }

}
```

The error I receive:

> error: class, interface, or enum expected

I appreciate the help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because `jsonAsynctask` is your activity not `AsyncTask`. Also you can not instantiate activity.

Comment: Hi, Piyush. I am not sure if I understand what you're saying. Can you elaborate?By the way thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: If you want to access your async task from activity then you can get `(jsonAsynctask)getActivity()).new jsonConnection ().execute();` instead of create instance of your activity. Also you can create asynctask in fragment rather then in activity.

Comment: I have updated my question, and I have edited the jsonAsynctask Java class, but I have received a new error.

Comment: Remove `extends MainActivity` from `jsonAsynctask`. Now declare in fragment class in declaration part like `jsonAsynctask mjsonTask;` Now in `onCreateView()` method make instance `mjsonTask = new jsonAsynctask();` After that call `mjsonTask.new jsonConnection ().execute();`

Comment: @Yas error: class, interface, or enum expected is due to extra paranthesis at end. Remove that paranthesis(})

Comment: Yes, just found it. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Bonus and last question:
Do you know why the for loop from "i < jsonasynctask.allId.size()" won't run? It stops after it runs "new jsonAsynctask().execute();" , and it doesn't run any code after "new jsonAsynctask().execute();" in onCreate().

Comment: I've written: "jsonasynctask.new jsonAsynctask().execute();", but jsonAsynctask() is red and have this: "error: cannot find symbol class jsonAsynctask"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating the separate class for AsynctTask is better, rather than creating AsyncTask in every fragment.
You are getting error because in 
   new jsonAsynctask().execute() // jsonAsyncTask extends from MainActivity, So its not a AsyncTask

Replace above line with  new jsonConnection .execute()

Comment: I've replaced the line with what you wrote, but i receive this error:

error: package jsonConnection does not exist

Comment: @Yas Remove jsonConnection  class out of the jsonAsynctask class. I mean you don't need jsonAsynctask class